# SQL Pivot on Conditional Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table of vulnerabilities using SQL server, when I perform the following query

```
select * from table
```

The output looks like so.

```
| Name          | HostName   | Week   |
| ------------- |------------| -------|
| java          | Hosta      |    1   |
| java          | Hostb      |    1   |
| java          | Hostb      |    2   |
| Ansible       | Hosta      |    1   |
| Ansible       | Hosta      |    2   |
| Ansible       | Hosta      |    3   |
| Ansible       | Hostb      |    3   |
```

My aim is to generate an output that pivots the weeks into column tables, with the values being a count of Hosts for a given vulnerability in that week.

```
| Vulnerability | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 |
| ------------- |--------| -------| -------|
| java          |    2   |    1   |    0   |
| Ansible       |    1   |    1   |    2   |
```

My initial attempt was to do

```
select * from table 
PIVOT(
count(HostName)
For week in ([1],[2],[3])
) AS OUT
```

But the output was the correct layout, but incorrect data as if it was only counting the first occurrence. 
Is an amendment to the count term required or is my approach the wrong one?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh sorry updated now, using SQL server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional aggregation is simpler:

```
select vulnerability,
       sum(case when week = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as week_1,
       sum(case when week = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as week_2,
       sum(case when week = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as week_3
from t
group by vulnerability;
```

Note only is `pivot` bespoke syntax, but it is sensitive to what columns are in the table.  Extra columns are interpreted as "group by" criteria, affecting the results from the query.

Comment: This was a life saver, although I could've gone with PIVOT but this is so much simpler... Thanks. Any way you can show the above using PIVOT too? Thanks